# Punctuation in Equation that finishes with superscript

Tags: math-mode, spacing, punctuation

I want to typeset something of the following form in display math

```
\begin{equation*}
    \Big(x\Big)^{1+2}.
\end{equation*}
```

After compiling it looks like

[image]

I understand why it is set like this. nevertheless I fear it is offsetting the reader.

*EDIT*: To be clear: both `x` and `{1+2}` are used as place-holders and are in fact fairly long expressions in my document. That makes the spacing look odd, I find.

I don't want to get into the debate whether punctuation in displayed math makes sense or not (I am not choosing styles anyways in that document).

However, I wonder about 2 things:

1. Is it appropriate to get rid of the spacing between brackets and dot? If not, why (I think there is no room for confusion and the extra spacing is interrupting the reader's flow)?
2. If it is appropriate, how can I do it? Do I have to stack `{1+2}` over `.`? Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: The dilemma could be solved *not* using `\Big`, but probably the real contents is not $x$?

Comment: The dot has a special meaning, it manifests that the sentence of the which equation is a part terminates. Therefor it should be manifest that punctuation does not belong to the equation, but to the sentence. Therefore the general rule, with or without this exponent is to insert an extra space with `\ ` or even `\quad` if you whish.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, infact there is no `\Big` in the real thing, but rather a `\left(` `\right)` which realizes as `\Big`

Comment: If you just need $(x)^{1+2}$, do nothing, it will be fine.

Comment: Ok, I should be clearer I guess. In reality both `base` and `exponent` are longer expressions which makes the spacing look odd. But, then maybe it is supposed to be like this.

Comment: Not TeX-related, but the idea of the fullstop is to make the reader make a pause. The equation inside `\[ \]` cannot be read without the pause, so, the fullstop may be avoided in such situations

Comment: If the period is set below the exponent, the reader will have a hard time getting a meaning out of it. On the other hand, I disagree with adding a space before punctuation in formulas. Probably your sentence should just not finish with the display.

Comment: I try to avoid ending sentences with display math, but when i do I add a \quad.

Comment: I think the period is fine. But when brackets get that big, I usually add one (or two) negative thin space `\!`. i.e, `^{\!1+2}`. You could also use the `\!` to move the period a bit to the left as well.